# How to transfer /wordpress folder from one PC to another

Tags: localhost

I am currently developing my own website, and I am hosting it locally using `WAMP`.

I thought that if I want to copy the website on some other PC I just have to copy the `/wordpress` folder to the `/www` folder of WAMP on the other computer, but seems like that's not working at all as I expected.

Can someone explain me what else do I need to copy in order for my website and hosting to be **exactly** the same as on the original computer?

Comment: I have to do the same thing here shortly since I updated from a Mac air to pro. I'll probably film a youtube video for all those who don't have extensive web development experience when I do. Everything that currently exists is either WAY above my experience level or not direction focused at all & fails to instruct or show how to do anything. I appreciate finding out that this isn't just an issue that I have dealt with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed to copy the database associated with WordPress install.

Go to `PHPmyAdmin`(http://localhost/phpmyadmin), Select the database and click `Export` all the tables.

In your other PC, Go to `PHPmyAdmin`, Create new user and a database. `Import` the file that was downloaded while exporting.

Answer (score 2):

You're failing to copy the database. Use the Duplicator plugin to create a copy of the entire site including the database. It will produce an archive zip file and an installer.php file (renaming it to installer.php is best). Copy them both to the local directory on the new PC. Use phpmyadmin to create a new database for the site on the new PCI and navigate to localhost/installer.php to start the setup